# Facebook login error code 3 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to add Facebook login to my app but I'm getting an error.

LoginVC.swift
[image]

Just to go through the checklist:

My plist looks fine

[image]

Also I enabled single sign on

[image]

I also implemented the shared instance in the appdelegate

AppDelegate.swift

[image]

Finally, obviously I imported both frameworks

[image]

Every time I press the button I get error code 3 though.

Any ideas?